# camel:when on header value using blueprint

Tags: xpath, apache-camel, jsonpath, blueprint-osgi

I have camel routes that make rest calls based on header values.
I had been using xpath to read values from xml and set them as the header and used xpath in a  block as so:

```
 <camel:setHeader headerName="clear">
    <xpath>/TicketInfo/TicketData/Clear/text()</xpath>
 </camel:setHeader>
    <camel:choice>
       <camel:when>
          <camel:xpath>$clear='CLEARED'</camel:xpath>
          <camel:doTry>
              ...
```

but now I am forced to use json so xpath will not work.  I now have:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="clear">
   <camel:jsonpath>$.ticket.Type</camel:jsonpath>
</camel:setHeader>
   <camel:choice>
      <camel:when>
         <camel:xpath>$clear='CLEARED'</camel:xpath>
         <camel:doTry>
            ...
```

but obviously the `<camel:xpath>$clear='CLEARED'</camel:xpath>` part won't work anymore.  Is there another way I can check the value of $clear header to restrict when the `<camel:doTry>` and following execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `simple` language :

```
<camel:when>
     <camel:simple>${in.header.clear} == 'CLEARED'</camel:simple>
     <camel:doTry>
```

See [this documentation](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)

Comment: Haha I figured there had to be a 'simple' way to make this work :) thanks!